# Share a BlockingCollection across multiple tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Here my scenario. I am getting a large amount of data in chuck from an external data source and I have to write it locally at two places. One of the destination is very slow to write to but the other one is super fast (but I cannot rely on it to read and write to the slow destination). To accomplish that, I am using a Producer-Consumer pattern (using BlockingCollection).

The issue I have right now is that I have to queue the data in two BlockingCollection and that takes way too much memory. My code look very similar to the example below but I would really like to drive the two Task from a single queue. Anybody know what would be the proper way to do that? Any inefficiencies in the code below?

```
class Program
{
    const int MaxNumberOfWorkItems = 15;
    static BlockingCollection<int> slowBC = new BlockingCollection<int>(MaxNumberOfWorkItems);
    static BlockingCollection<int> fastBC = new BlockingCollection<int>(MaxNumberOfWorkItems);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task slowTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (var item in slowBC.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SLOW -> " + item);
                Thread.Sleep(25);
            }
        });

        Task fastTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (var item in fastBC.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FAST -> " + item);
            }
        });

        // Population two BlockingCollections with the same data. How can I have a single collection?
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            while (slowBC.TryAdd(i) == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wait for slowBC...");
            }

            while (fastBC.TryAdd(i) == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wait for 2...");
            }
        }

        slowBC.CompleteAdding();
        fastBC.CompleteAdding();

        Task.WaitAll(slowTask, fastTask);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: not a real answer, but FWIW, an alternative approach would be using TPL DataFlow where you could have a BroadcastBlock that sent to 2 different ActionBlock's for the 2 different write paths.  The main benefit of this kind of approach is to keep from having to manage the 'linking' collections manually.

Comment: Similarly, of course, you could use Rx, create an observable, and have 2 subscribers AFAICT.

Comment: Those are two very good idea but I must stick with what is available in .NET 4.0 (and no RX)... :(

Comment: What's your goal in terms of runtime blocking behavior?  For instance,  given the speed difference, one alternative would be to just take that foreach and have its body write to first the fast one and then the slow one.  Would that be fine, or is it important that the fast one 'run ahead' of the slower one?

Comment: It's important that the fast one run ahead of the slow one. Essentially the fast one populates a distributed cache and the slow one write to MySQL. Having the distributed cache populated first is important.

Comment: then why not just do it synchronously? first write to the distributed cache, and then the db. No concurrent queues, no tasks, no contention, no multithreading... no problem :-P

Comment: Why? Because I cannot fetch the data twice.

Comment: A simple solution would be simply to fire off two tasks for each item. This means that you'll consume items as fast as they become available. Another option is to update your cache synchronously and fire off the DB update as a task. This will consume items as fast as the cache allows.

Comment: @Martin - this is likely not a good idea, but if your concern is the doubled memory usage, then instead of doing the 2 in parallel, you could do them serially.  So you'd still have 2 BC's, but instead of sending copies to both, you send to the fast one, which sends it to the slow one inside its foreach (either before or after it finishes its write, based on what you want the behavior to be if the fast one fails to write)

Comment: Busy waiting on `TryAdd()` is a terrible idea, it wastes CPU time for no reason. Use the fact that it's a *blocking* collection and use the blocking `Add()`.

Comment: I know you have said .NET 4.0 only but it is a great fit for Disruptor, http://code.google.com/p/disruptor-net/   You could take some of the ideas (which are quite simple) and use it. It is a circle buffer which can have many readers (one slow, one fast). Just need a sufficient buffer size that the slow reader doesnt starve the fast reader

Answer (score 0):

1. Using a producer-consumer queue to transfer single ints is extremely inefficient.  You are rx it in chunks, so why not type the queue as '*chunk' and send the whole chunk, immediately creating/depooling a new chunk at the same ref. varaible to rx. the next lot of data?  This is how P-C queues are normally be used for non-trivial amounts of data - queueing refs/pointers, not actual data.  Threads have shared memory spaces, (that some developers seem to think just causes problems), so use it - queue pointers/refs and safely transfer MB of data as one pointer.  As long as you, IN THE NEXT LINE OF CODE, always create/depool a new one after queueing off the old one, the producer and consumer threads can never be operating on the same chunk.

   Queueing *chunks is powers-of-10 times more efficient for large chunks.
2. Send the *chunks to the fast link then just 'forward' them to the slow link from there.
3. You may need flow-control overal if the slow link is not to block up your system and cause eventual OOM errors.  What I usually do is fix an 'overall' quota for the total buffer size and create a pool of chunks at startup, (pool is another BlockingCollection, populated with *new(chunks) at startup). The producer thread dequeues chunks, fills them with data, queues them to the FAST thread.  The FAST thread processes received chunks and then queues the *chunks to the SLOW thread.  The SLOW thread processes the same data and then repools the 'used' chunk for re-use by the producer thread.  This forms a flow-controlled system - if the SLOW thred is too slow, the producer eventually tries to depool a *chunk from an empty pool and so blocks there until the SLOW thread repools some used *chunks and so signals the producer thread to run again. You may need some policy in the slow thread to time-out its operations and dump its *chunk early, so dropping data - you must decide on a policy for that given your overall requirements - it is obviously impossible to continually queue data to a fast and slow consumer forever without memory overflow unless the slow consumer dumps some data.

Edit - Oh, and yes, using a pool eliminates GC on the used chunks, further increasing performance.

One overall flow policy would be to not dump any data in the slow thread.  With continual high data flow, the *chunks will all end up being on the queue between the fast and slow threads and the producer thread will indeed block on the empty pool.  The network connection wil then apply its own flow-contol to stop the network peer sending any more dat over TCP.  This extends the flow -control all the way from your slow thread to the peer.